# selecting high K values while making leave one out CV in KNN weka for regression problems

Tags: machine-learning, regression, weka, data-mining, knn

I am trying to compute a regression problem in weka using **IBk (KNN) algorithm.**

Recently I came acroos strange result of correlation coefficent value of **-1**.

Can I assign K as a very large number? Lets say K equals to a number of instances of my dataset and When I set the K value to very high, can I make the leave one out cross validation?

If both of them are true and not problemmatic. 
How can we interpret the r=-1 result?

As r=-1 means very strong negative correlation. So Do you think whether I made mistake by setting K as a large number and making **LOOCV** at the same time, with respect to machine learning and statistics points of view?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the first question:

If you assign `k=n` then all data points are the nearest neighbour. The result is then basically the average/most likely value.

Concerning your second question:

A very high value is neither a good idea. There are typically too many data points which are not any more similar to the original value. The goal of kNN is typically to deal with outliers and noise. But this does only require a few additional data points

**BUT** what you could do is to do a weighted k-NN where each data point is weighted by its distance. However, this is typically to costly.

Comment: first of all thanks you for quick response. Here what i would like to know getting r=-1 result from the weka using KNN with K equals to the number of instances was reliable or not. Please answer this statement.

Comment: This might be, however, seems to be a bit too strong negative correlation. One Explanation, for the classification case, is if you assume, that you have n/2 postivie and n/2 negative examples. If you draw, for example, a negative in the LOOCV. There are n/2 pos and (n/2-1) negative examples in the training set as k = n-1 (size of train) the resulting classification is postitive